# Cordova: Cannot call method 'exec' of undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am making use Facebook Connect Plugin with Cordova/Phonegap has explained here(https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect). I have included my Facebook SDk js file, also included the FB Cordova js file, I have not included the Cordova.js file itself cause it seems to have been included in Ripple Emulator(Testing with Ripple), when I ty to call the login method in the Facebook JS file I get the exception in the try-catch block:  'Cannot call method 'exec' of undefined'

Here is a snaphot of my code

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
                                  try {
                                  alert('Device is ready! Make sure you set your app_id below this alert.');
                                  FB.init({ appId: "appid", nativeInterface: CDV.FB, useCachedDialogs: false });
                                  document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = "";
                                  } catch (e) {
                                  alert(e);
                                  }
                                  }, false);
```

From Chrome dev tools, I see in the call stack [native code] in the function that is being called could this be the reason, does this mean I have to test on the device?

ANy suggestion would appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include the **cordova.js** file when you test the page with Ripple emulator. Ripple emulator only simulates the mobile environment, you still need to have the cordova.js file which defines the Cordova object.

Phonegap plugins use ***Cordova.exec*** to call a native method from javascript. Your Facebook plugin will also use that method to make native method calls. Also make sure to include the 'cordova.js' before the facebook plugin js files in your page.

Comment: Cordova calls native methods, would that be the reason why I am getting this error in Ripple emulator, does this mean Ripple does not make available thi native methods

Comment: I don't think so. The native calls are all simulated by Ripple. The plugin js will have to call exec method on 'Cordova' object. But if the cordova.js is not include before that, 'Cordova' will be undefined so you get the 'Cannot call method 'exec' of undefined.

Comment: Ya you a right, there seem to be an uncompatibility problem with the cordova/phonegap environment using the right version(2.0.0) in Ripple fixed the issue